# How can i read a char* from user space when i'm in kernel space?

Tags: c, module, io

I need to test a char* in order to compare if it has a length between 0 and 3, if the characters are '1', '2' or '3' and if they aren't repeated. I'm working in kernel space (Programming a module) and i do not know how to format it, i'm using copy_to_user, but i don't know how to know the length of the char[](not the byte length, the max index of the char array) my current code fails and takes weird characters sometimes. This is  a driver, so while i write in the associated file (using fprintf) from another unrelated file, gets trash with it.

```
static ssize_t module_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off){ 

char aux[BUF_MAX_LEN];
int salir =0;
int i =0;
//[...]

if(copy_from_user(aux,buff, len ) ) //Sometimes this makes a copy of random characters because of the length
     return -EINVAL;

        for (i = 0; salir == 0;i++){

            if(aux[i] == '3'){
//              [...]
            }else if(aux[i] == '1'){
//              [...]
            }else if(aux[i]== '2'){
//              [...]
            }else if(aux[i] == '\n' || aux[i] == '\0'){
                salir++;
            }else{
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Error, character not valid");
                return -EINVAL;
            }
            if(i >=3) return -EINVAL;
        }

//[...]
    return length;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`strlen()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=strlen)? P.s. you know you can just `break` out of a loop, right?

Comment: When i use strlen, if i write 'echo 123 > /dev/mydev' the length is 4 and adds a (i don't know how it is told in english) line jump. But when i write 'echo "12" > /dev/mydev' the length is also 4